# Is it possible to identify the end of a scroll in pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a scrollable list of items, I iterate through the entire list. If it finds the element I'm looking for during the iteration, it selects it and stops. But if it doesn't find it, pywinauto reaches the end of the scroll and enters an infinite loop. Is it possible to identify when I am at the end of the scroll to end the operation?

Specifications:

- Pywinauto 0.6.8
- Python 3.10.7
- Windows 10

Comment: In theory scroll bar control should have ValuePattern (it can be checked in Inspect.exe) or RangeValuePattern (can be accessed by `.iface_range_value` attribute of a wrapper). I see the second pattern for vertical scroll bar in explorer.exe. Not sure about your application. I even can set Value to 100.0 (end of scroll down) from Inspect.exe menu "Action".